# Is it possible to preserve space for error label in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I have multiple TextInputLayouts in my layout, and I need to validate fields (and show error text if they are not valid).

But `TextView` that contains error is added by `TextInputLayout` dynamically, so it changes layout height and all views at the bottom are moving lower by the height of added `TextView`.

So the question is: can I preserve space for error text even when error is not showing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `textInputLayout` add this :`app:errorEnabled="true"`

Comment: Wow, I thought it would change line color to red, but it did not :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @arts777